# Shift primary key values to start from 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have table with documents and there are about 100 documents.

I would like next document Id to be 1000, 1001, 1002 etc

Can I shift next Id value somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  You "reseed" the IDENTITY column like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTableName, reseed, 999)
```

That would make the next IDENTITY value to be 1000.

Be careful to never set the reseed value to be LOWER than the highest value currently in the table, or there will be constraint violations in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean your primary key column has an `IDENTITY` set, and you want to change its next value, then use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 999)
```

(the 999 is one less than the next value 1000).